# Removing Formula from Excel Blank Cells automatically

Tags: vba, excel

How can i remove Formula from Excel Blank Cell, For Example i have these formula in one of the Blank Cells in Excel Dynamically.

`=IF('filepath[filename.xls]Sheet1'!$A$1:A$65536="","",'filepath[filename.xls]Sheet1'!$A$1:A$65536)`.

Thanks

Comment: Press the delete button?...

Comment: @Balinti I want it to be automatically

Comment: at what moment? anytime a cell changes, or just before closing the workbook?

Comment: @A.S.H anytime a cell changes, if the source have some value i want to show that value but if the source cell is blank i want to hide the above formula or `=IF('filepath[filename.xls]Sheet1'!$A$1:A$65536="","",'filepath[filename.xls]Sheet1'!$A$1:A$65536)`.  I am using the excel file to import data into an application

Comment: @Keven add a handler Worksheet_Calculate() in your worksheet as in my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be some simple macro as:

```
Sub Macro1()



For Each c In Worksheets("your sheet name").Range("your range")

   If c.Value = "" Then c.Select: Selection.ClearContents
   Next c

End Sub
```

Where "your sheet name" can be for example "Sheet1"

and "your range" can be for example "a1:a10"

Comment: What have you inserted in the sheet name and your range? did you use double quotes (")?

Comment: Here is what run`Sub Macro1()



For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a2:a10")

   If c.Value = "" Then c.Select: Selection.ClearContents
   Next c

End Sub
`

Comment: Do you have a sheet named "Sheet1" in your current workbook?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim cell As Range
    On Error GoTo finish
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each cell In UsedRange
       If cell.Text = "" Then cell.Clear
    Next

finish:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately there is no way for Excel to provide a truly empty cell if it contains a formula, but I have a way to empty the cells:

- Create an if statement that, if false, returns **`ERROR.TYPE(1)`**.
- From there, select the range of cells you want to delete the intended "blanks" from and use **"Find and Select" >> "Go to Special"**.
- Click on the **"Formulas"** radio button and leave **"Errors" as the only box checked**.  Clicking OK will **highlight all the cells that were assigned the value "#N/A"**.
- Now just press the delete key.